# Remove # from end of URL added by clicking jQuery scrollTop button with href="#"

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I am writing a new Joomla 3x template to work with Bootstrap 4x. I have included a 'Go to top' link which appears at the bottom of the page. In the index.php this is entered as:

```
<div id="gotop" class=""><a href="#" class="scrollup">Go to top</a></div>
```

And in my template.js file I have the following, which works fine:

```
     jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    if ( jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 1200) {
         jQuery("#gotop").addClass("gotop_active");
    } else {
         jQuery("#gotop").removeClass("gotop_active");
    }
}); 
jQuery(".scrollTop").click(function(){
    jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
    return false;
});
```

However, when I click the button on the page and am returned to the top, the URL is now mywebsite/current-page#

If I remove the # from the href="#" (i.e. href="") I do not get returned to the top of the current page, but to the top of the home page.

The same code (where I copied it from) is in another template, written some years ago (not by me) and the # is not added to the URL.

So, can someone please tell me how do I stop the # being added to the current page's URL?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe change the `class="scrollup"` in the anchor to scrollTop, like your JS uses.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but it makes no difference and is how it was in the original version.

Comment: The code you have should already accomplish your goals. Look for errors in the console and make sure the element you are targeting exists *and matches the selector you are using*.

Comment: There are no errors in the console and I am not targeting a specific element; just the top of the page. You can view the site here: https://new2bsd.websiteprep.co.uk

Comment: This question doesn't have anything to do with Joomla, but if you have a Joomla-centric question in the future please post at Joomla Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my original post, this template uses Bootstrap 4x, at the time of writing, v4.1.3.

I added the links to the files in my index.php as outlined on Bootstrap's page [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/)

After testing these files one by one I have discovered that this file [jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js](http://%3Cscript%20src=%22https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js%22%20integrity=%22sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo%22%20crossorigin=%22anonymous%22%3E%3C/script%3E) is causing the conflict. I removed the link and now the 'Go to top' function works correctly. I'm not sure, however, how not including this link is going to affect my template in the future, but it seems to be working fine at the moment. (I also removed the popper.js link as I don't need it at this stage... EDIT: Oops. I do need popper.js).